# What's a good tool to monitor network activity

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp

I'm operating a neighbourhood [WIFI network in a rural environment](http://maps.google.de/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=de&msa=0&msid=101021148567197540440.00043fcffa4cdf06fb4bc&ll=51.791948,8.173571&spn=0.033976,0.058365&t=h&z=14).

Now I'm looking fo a monitoring tool to run on a server (Windows or Linux) which would track bandwidth, uptime (clients as well as internet connection), etc... 
Most of this information is exposed via SNMP by my routers and access points, so SNMP support is required.

Additional features should be:

- Graphical data representation
- free license

So what's the best choice for me?

*Edit* These are the tools mentioned so far:

- [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/)
- [Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
- [Zenoss Core](http://www.zenoss.com/product/core)
- [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/)
- [cacti](http://cacti.net/features.php)
- [ZABBIX](http://www.zabbix.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) is probably the easiest to setup. If your router has SNMP (as you mention), to setup it's a single command:

```
cfgmaker --output=mrtg_myrouter.cfg public@1.2.3.4
```

MRTG is good for high-bandwidth routers and the likes. It's not great for other data (it can be coerced into graphing most things, but it's a little unintuitive to setup)

For monitoring other stuff I like [Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/). I would describe it again, but I posted an answer a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737/generate-disk-usage-graphscharts-with-cli-only-tools-in-linux#43733) (about graphing disc-usage).

Munin can of course graph network usage, and easily pull data via SNMP (in fact it's the recommended setup for grabbing data from Windows-based servers - run a SNMP daemon on the Windows machine, and have Munin connect to this). The graphs are also prettier than MRG, I would say (clearly the most important factor..)

There's an example installation of [MRTG here](http://www.switch.ch/network/operation/statistics/geant2.html), and [Munin here](http://munin.ping.uio.no/)

Comment: In fact I mentioned SNMP (Network Monitpring) not SMTP (Mail Transfer), but the answer seems to only confuse the terms.

Comment: Err, opps. I meant SNMP, not SMTP..

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, [Cacti](http://cacti.net/) is easiest to install and use.

[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) is interesting, but harder to use.

And [here](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/xorg/nmtf/nmtf-tools.html) is a very comprehensive list of all network monitoring tools.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fits your usage but a lot of web hosting provider uses  [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) for network monitoring

Answer (score 1):

[Zenoss Core](http://www.zenoss.com/product/core) is free and open source. It keeps RRD graphs (like other monitoring tools mentioned here). To monitor parameters other than basic network bandwidth (and up state), the switch or router SNMP definitions and MIBs should be available as a [ZenPack](http://www.zenoss.com/community/projects/zenpacks/). Runs on a Linux (virtual?) server. Uses Google Maps to display link status.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) it is free on linux and for purchase if you want a windows binary and worked pretty well for us

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question last week and tried several options.

For basic snmp graphing needs, **cacti** is great, but graphing apache, mysql, etc. is a bit too hard I think.

**ntop** is also a nice tool, but has a different usecase than the other ones in your list.

You should look at **Zenoss**. The Core version is FOSS, userfriendly, and very powerful. I had no need for the Enterprise version, but your needs may differ.
It does graphing, monitoring and alerting of all the basic stats, but download some ZenPacks and you can easily add Apache, MySQL or many other stats. All configuration can be done via the GUI. The interface is clear and responsive and allows for easy management of very large networks.

In short, I'm glad I never spent much time on **Nagios**, because I believe Zenoss is the best option available.

Comment: Meanwhile I started with mrtg on a xubuntu server. I got this set up quite easily but have found that it comsumes some time once you start trying to customize it. So maybe I'll have a look at Zenoss.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [CactiEZ](http://cactiez.cactiusers.org/) on a VM or small server, it is a baremetal CentOS 6 based system.